# Size of OPENGL context in SFML WINDOW

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, sfml

i'm currently working on a voxel editor and everything is going fine.

I have my SFML windows and my model to work with. I was just wondering if it was possible with SFML to set the 3D context to a certain specefic size.

I'm asking this because my model is currently shown on the screen with not problem at all, except that now, I want to create some options settings with SFML and my button will on my 3D model. Like, I would like 75% of the left side of my window to be my 3D context and the 25% at the right to be blank with space to fill in my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want to do, I believe what you're looking for is this: http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1View.php#details

I think the context is attached to the window in general. Also be aware that SFML is for 2D graphics. Once you want 3D rendering, you're going to need to use openGL directly. SFML is a wrapper for openGL calls so there's no problem with using SFML to help set up and manage things, and openGL directly for rendering needs.

http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-opengl.php

Answer (score 0):

try:
glViewport(x,y,width,height);

source: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glViewport.xml